# link won't inherit width of list element

Tags: html, css

I can't get the links in the nav bar to stretch the full width of each list element.  Thus, when the user puts their mouse over the nav bar list element (but not the linked text within it), clicking does not take them to the desired page.

```css
.nav_bar
{
    width:100%
}
.nav_bar ul
{
    padding:5px;
    width:100%;

    background-color:#50AF36; 
}
.nav_bar li
{
    padding:5px 7% 5px 7%;
    margin:0px;

    position:relative; /*acts as container for drop-down*/

    display:inline-block;

    font-size:20pt;
    color:white;
}
.nav_bar li:hover
{
    background-color:#47d620;
}
.nav_bar a
{
    display:block;

    width:inherit;

    text-decoration:none;
    color:inherit;
}
/*----------Hideable Dropdown Menu----------*/
.nav_bar ul li ul
{
    position:absolute;  /*create drop-down just below nave list item*/
    left:0px;

    padding:0px;
    margin-top:5px;

    display:none;
}
.nav_bar ul li:hover ul
{
    display:block;
}
.nav_bar ul li ul li
{
    padding:0 10px;
    margin:0;

    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `padding` from the `li` and add it into `a` tag. And do the same for `hover` styles for the background.

```
.nav_bar li {
    padding: 0;
}

.nav_bar li a {
    padding: 5px 30px;
}

.nav_bar li a:hover {
    background-color:#47d620;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  This does make the anchors wider, but unfortunately it results on nav buttons of different widths, depending on the length of the word in the nav bar (for example, "Contact" is now wider than "Home"...is there a way to fix this?  The bars were previously the same width when padding inside the <li> element.

Comment: You can give the `a` tag a fixed width for that, demo http://jsfiddle.net/pLxgtpL0/1/

Comment: Interesting!  I think I get it...so it looks like the <li> element is adjusting its width based on the <a> element.  Nice!  The only thing I'm missing from before is that the spacing of the nav buttons used to adjust based on page width (had padding set as %), but setting the <a> element padding as a % seems to glitch things out (links overlap each other).  Any idea why?  I'm not planning on adding the feature back, I'm just curious :D  Thanks again!

Comment: Percentage width is depending on the width of the elements' parent. You can give the <li> nn% width and make 100%, that should do what you need. http://jsfiddle.net/pLxgtpL0/2/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the padding in your li element. The anchor sits inside the padding so only gets limited width. My suggestion is that you take the padding off the li element and add it to a span which you can sit inside the anchor tag. Like this:

```
  <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
```

update the css like this:

```
 .nav_bar li span{
   padding:5px 7% 5px 7%;
   display:block;
}
```

.nav_bar li
     {
      padding:0px;
      margin:0px;

```
  position:relative; /*acts as container for drop-down*/

  display:inline-block;

  font-size:20pt;
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: @sdcr solution is better as it is simpler - doesn't require the span.

Comment: I'm going with sdcr's solution, but thanks anyways Leo!